# Como evitar problemas de performance com tabelas que contem muitos dados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de folha de pagamentos, no qual há um "problema' em uma de suas tabelas.
Pois, para controlar os descontos no holerite de cada funcionário, pensei em criar uma tabela com o nome: Descontos que teria os campos, como: `id,`dia/hora`,`tipo`,`valor_descontado`,`observações`. No entanto, esta tabela futuramente ficará com muitos registros devido a empresa ter 150 funcionários

**Obs**: Como eu poderia moldar melhor essa parte do sistema para evitar problemas a longo prazo?

Comment: Pesquise sobre o uso de índices (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: adicione índices ao seu banco de dados, que fazem com que tabelas com milhões de registros sejam percorridos de forma mais rápida sem perder a perfomance

Comment: Você pode também além de usar índices como os amigos acima falaram, pode mover os dados de meses atrás para uma segunda tabela.

Comment: O que o @IagoLeão disse é uma boa e eu implementei assim, todo final de mês, automatizei meu sistema para salvar em uma outra tabela tudo que foi feito no mês presente, e apaga o do mês anterior, assim sua tabela de produção, além dos índices já postos, terá menos stress para trabalhar.

Comment: Vou seguir as dicas, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º A modelagem de dados da tabela está bem feita? Pois dependendo da construção da tabela você pode substituir o tipo como "TIPOABCDE" para 1, minimizando a quantidade de bytes por registro e consequentemente diminuindo o tempo de busca na tabela.

Também veja o qanto normalizada suas tabelas estão. Deixe na tabela principal apenas índices referenciando relacionamentos com outras tabelas, evitando deixar carga demais em uma única tabela tornando-a pesada demais.

2º O tal 'problema' seria performance? O problema ocorreria durante uma consulta em uma tabela ou um relatório?

Neste caso talvez o problema não esteja em uma grande quantidade de dados na tabela, portanto uma coluna auxiliar contento mês/Ano indexada poderia acelerar a busca dependendo da query, ou simplesmente tentando corrigí-la caso houverem joins mal feitos (o que acaba com a performance do banco)

Outra maneira de diminuir o tempo de processamento é usar as técnicas de "subquery factoring", que se bem utilizadas podem diminuir em muito o tempo de uma consulta

3º A máquina onde é feito este sistema de processamento é dedicada? Caso negativo você pode ter problemas de performance não por conta de seu sistema, mas por conta de concorrência deste sistema com os outros da máquina.